# xcode 6 GM - NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo

Tags: swift, xcode6, nsfetchedresultscontroller

with last xcode release (GM) I'm having a lot of errors building my project that with previous version were not spotted like the following code

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections[section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
    println("numberOfRowsInSection: \(self.entityName()) : \(sectionInfo.numberOfObjects)")
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}
```

I rewrite this with the following:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
    if let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections {
        println("numberOfRowsInSection: \(self.entityName()) : \(sectionInfo[section].numberOfObjects)")
        return sectionInfo[section].numberOfObjects

    }
return 0
}
```

is there a better and correct way write this?

Comment: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo is a protocol, not a class.

Answer (score 1):

Since Xcode 6 beta 6 or 7, `NSFetchedResultsController`'s `sections` property is an optional. Therefore, Apple now uses the following code in Xcode 6 GM Master-Detail Application template with Core Data activated (note that this code is for `UITableViews` but it should also be applied for `UICollectionViews` in `-collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:`):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections![section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}
```

If you put a breakpoint in this method and launch your Xcode 6 GM Master-Detail Application template for the first time, you will see that this method is called and that `sectionInfo` has a value, even if there is no items to return after the initial fetch request.

Although I would have preferred optional binding for more clarity here, I guess that if you strictly follow the Apple Core Data pattern, it may not be harmful to reuse this code (without doing an optional binding). Anyway, your optional binding code seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly i don't program in swift but i think that this Obj-C code snippet should help you to refactor your code:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger rows = 0;

    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count] > 0) {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        rows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: this is similar to what I just use with objective-c, and it worked as usual. the problem is with swift